# laravel 5 - Share a variable across controllers (without rendering a view)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a small application developed with Laravel, and I would like to share a variable (a result from a remote service, cached ) across all the controllers.

I read about ViewComposer, but they only work is a view is rendered (makes sense), and my app has many json responses.

I know that I could traditionally extend my controllers from a BaseController, but I wonder if anybody knows a way to do that without relying on inheritance.

Comment: If it's cached, you can just access it through `Cache::get('yourvar')` wherever you need it?

Comment: Set the variable in the session. `Session::put(key,value)` then `Session::get(value) or in 5.x session(value)`. Hope this help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that result into an object that's responsible for the caching, that you can DI that class into the controller - either in the constructor, or the specific route methods.

( If you're using laravel's caching service, then you can inject that with no extra work. )

super basic example:

```
class CachedResult {

  public function result() {
      return 'woo! caching';
  }

}

...
// in your controller...
public function someJsonRoute(CachedResult $result) {
    $result->result();
}

...
// in your AppServiceProvider's register method
$this->app->singleton(CachedResult::class, function() { return new CachedResult; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable and/or function for the remote service in the base controller.

And in a controller that extends the base controller, you could use it like this:

$this->varName;